# set default value for a select field which depends on another select field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

In my rails app I'm using 'devise'.
I add also for users the "Institution" select field and the "Campus" select field,
when the user selects one "Institution" the field "Campus" changes
so far everything is ok, my problem is when I want to edit the user's profile.

when I go to edit I want that the select fields default values be the ones the user belongs.
This for solved the problem only for "Institution":

```
= select_tag(:institution, options_for_select(Instituicao.all.map {|institution| institution.name, institution.id] },
      [current_user.campus.institution.name, current_user.campus.institution.id])
```

but for "Campus" I couldn't make it to get the default value as the user's "Campus" which he already belong, this is how the "Campus" select is right now:

```
= select_tag(:campus, options_for_select(Institution.first.campus.map {|campus| [campus.name, campus.id] })
```

Comment: Already solve it, but I have to wait 5 hours to put my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my own question:

Just do the Campus select field like this:

```
= select_tag(:campus, options_for_select(current_user.campus.institution.campus.map {|campus| [campus.name, campus.id] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= select_tag(:campus, 
  options_for_select(
    Institution.all.campus.map {|campus| [campus.name, campus.id] },
    current_user.campus.id # ???  don't really know how your relationships are set up
  )
```

It looks like a user belongs to a campus,  and a campus belongs to an institution,  but you didn't post enough code to know for sure.

Your first working example could be reduced to:

```
= select_tag(:institution, 
  options_for_select(
    Instituicao.all.map {|institution| institution.name, institution.id] },
    current_user.campus.institution.id)
```

Comment: that doesn't work for several reasons: `Institution.all` is an array, it doesn't has the `campus` method. And what you suggested would give all the campus in the database, I want just the campus wich belongs to the selected "Institution". But thanks man. =]